# Show full site names in the Migration 10k tool

Tags: feature-request, design, migration, 10k-tools

The layout of the [Migration 10k tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=) is weird:

> [image]

I think that the page should be changed so that the entire site name is shown instead of just, for example, "Project Mana...". There's no need for everything to end in "Stack Exchange" here either.

A good way to do this would be to put everything into a stricter grid layout, where the bottom of the right column doesn't hang below the dividers. Also, it would make sense to allow the content to go into that great ocean of white on the right side of the page. It would also look better if the site icons were more centered, instead of right justified.

Hopefully this can be done when the page is made responsive. It would also fix a few issues I see:

- The names of some sites have an ellipsis when they don't need to (e.g. "Aviation Met...", "Bitcoin Meta...", "Travel Meta ...")
- The meta and main sites usually have the same label due to the truncation. What's worse is that ELU, ELL, and both of their metas have the same label ("English Lang...").

Comment: FYI, if you hover over the icon, it shows a [tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWZ7z.png) containing the URL (not the name) of the site. Not ideal, but it's a decent workaround until this b̶u̶g̶ feature request is f̵i̵x̵e̵d̵ implemented.