# Show full site names on Recently returned migrations page

Tags: feature-request, migration, 10k-tools

On the 10k tools page with [recently returned migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/returned), all but the shortest site names are truncated, while there is enough space to display the entire site name:

[image]

Comment: This can create confusion between, say, Mathematics and Mathematics Educators.

Comment: Did they redesign this page? This is essentially the same as my previous question ([Show full site names in the Migration 10k tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322307/323179)), but I don't remember it looking exactly like this.

Comment: @Laurel thanks, I failed to find that one. Here is how that looks now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Let0S.png - there's a lot less space there, presumably because of the site logos.